# Accessing JSON key/value

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get a key/value from a JSON object, trying to get them from an array.

```
    var ii;
    var s;
    var networksArray = [ "a" ];
    var len = networksArray.length;

    for (ii=0; ii<len; ++ii) {
      if (ii in networksArray) {
        currentNetwork = networksArray[ii];
        alert (markersList[i].a); //works
        alert (markersList[i].currentNetwork); //doesn't work
      }
    }
```

The first alert works as expected; the second alert does not work. Must be missing something basic.

I'd like
    markersList[i].currentNetwork
to be interpreted as
    markersList[i].a
but I think I am mixing strings with variables ...

Thanks for helping.

Comment: How would we know what to do when no data sample is provided?

Comment: Can you show your JSON object and what is markersList, and where its defiend? Are you getting any errors in your console? the code you are showing is not descriptive enough. What is markersList.a? where does it get set?

Comment: where is json object you are testing with simple array.

Comment: The code does not output any error. But the alert returns "undefined". The JSON object is defined before the FOR LOOP, but in the same file...

Comment: I think the data is irrelevant in this case. It's just a way of trying to access "markersList[i].a" (which works) but I am trying to get the "a" from the networksArray.

Comment: we know nothing about the structure of markersList, so we can't answer your question.

Comment: Here's a sample: var markersList = [{"a":"a-value"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, changing `markersList[i].currentNetwork` to `markersList[i][currentNetwork]` should solve this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It worked perfectly. I do not understand why I got so many downvotes, perhaps I did not express myself correctly. But, as I guessed, it had nothing to do with data but with syntax. Thanks again!